# How do I prevent Eclipse Indigo from shutting down my server after 45 seconds?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat6, eclipse-indigo

I have run into a problem with Eclipse Indigo, attempting to start up my Tomcat v6.0 server. I’ll start my server, the console will report that the server has started up (after so many milliseconds), and the server console will look fine and the server will accept requests correctly. But then 45 seconds later (or whatever the default timeout is set to), Eclipse will shut down the server and say that the server encounted a problem and was unable to start.

One way to get around the problem is to change the server timeout time to 9999 seconds instead of the default 45, but obviously this is not ideal.

Comment: How long does Tomcat actually take to start-up and output the "Server started in xx seconds" message?

Comment: Much less than the xx seconds.  In my specific example, the server is up and ready in about 15 seconds.  Basically the problem is that Eclipse doesn't detect the successful startup for some reason and then automatically shuts down when reaching the timeout duration.

Comment: If it's waiting on a connection (JDPA etc.) then it will only send the start-up successful message once it's got its expected response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some Googling but I discovered the resolution to this issue at http://dsamuel.kodingen.com/_writeit/wordpress/?p=18. What you have to do is just change your host name to something (anything) other than the default name of “localhost”, and this will actually fix the problem. You can change host name by double-clicking your server and editing it in the “General Information” area.

No idea why this fixes the problem, but it does. It appears to be a bug with Eclipse Indigo particularly because it doesn’t happen for Helios.